# what can I do so that my C script can execute binary file?

Tags: c, shell

so I did the `gcc -Wall -o file file.c`, my program works with `echo abc | ./file`, however when I try `sh file abc`, it says `file : file cannot execute binary file`, what can I do to fix this issue? my C prototype is `int main(int argc, char **argv)`, not sure if this helps.

Thanks!

Comment: The shell (`/bin/sh`) can only execute shell scripts.  If you want to execute a binary file, you run that file, as you are already doing by running `./file`.

Comment: just type ./file abc

Answer (score 0):

You tried to execute file (that is a compiled executable) as a shell script. That doesn't work. Did you mean

```
sh -c ./file
```

Answer (score 0):

- Your `file` is not a script, but a binary.
- Trying to execute it with `sh` implies it is a sh/bash script.
- Try with `./file`.